# How to get a List Element of a Map

Tags: apex, list, map

I have a map `Map<Id, list<Boolean>> mapOfIdAndListBoolean = new Map<Id, list<Boolean>>();`
I think I can get the whole list by using `mapOfIdAndListBoolean .get(order.AccountId)`. Would I get the first element of the list by using `mapOfIdAndListBoolean .get(order.AccountId)[0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will get the first element of the List.

Try below code for understanding in anonymous window.

```
Map<String, list<Boolean>> mapOfIdAndListBoolean = new Map<String, list<Boolean>>();

mapOfIdAndListBoolean.put('testStr',new List<Boolean>{true,false,true});
system.debug(mapOfIdAndListBoolean);
Boolean value = mapOfIdAndListBoolean.get('testStr')[0];
system.debug(value);
```

Comment: But You need to be very sure that you will not get "null" for the "key" here. Otherwise, you run into Null Pointer Exception